# The await expression can only be used in an async function

Tags: flutter, dart

I create function in flutter to convert images assets to file and when I call this function with await, the error tell me to add async in the body of my function :

```
Future<File> getImageFileFromAssets(String path) async {
  final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$path');

  final file = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$path');
  await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer
      .asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));

  return file;
}
```

the call :

```
File ppBase = await getImageFileFromAssets('ppBase.png');
```

Can you help me please

I don't know what is the problem

Comment: can you share where you're calling that method? I mean in which method did you wrote this code File ppBase = await getImageFileFromAssets('ppBase.png'); ?

Comment: after the imports

Comment: As per the flutter documentation you can't call Future method outside async function. In detail you need to call that method inside async method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your method to `async` to use `await`

```dart
yourMethod() async { //here async
   File ppBase = await getImageFileFromAssets('ppBase.png');
```

Comment: thanks sorry I'm beginner 

Comment: it's ok, you can check this [codelabs](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)